# How to get a dynamic number into a chart.js chart?

Tags: javascript, html, json, animation, chart.js

I would like to make a doughnut chart of the number of positively tested persons on Coronavirus and the number of deaths related to coronavirus, how do I get the same numbers as in the top container into the chart? So confirmedCases and deaths need to be put into the doughnut chart.

Thanks a lot. I am sorry for asking so many questions, but I learned a lot from your answers and I am slowly progressing, but I am still a beginner at all of this.

```js
let tId;
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("countrySel").addEventListener("change", getCovidStats);
  document.getElementById("countrySel").value = "169";
  getCovidStats()
})

// Zorgt voor de optel annimatie
function countUp() {
  cnt += 100;
  let done = 0;
  let iMax = +document.getElementById('inwoners').getAttribute("max");
  if (cnt < iMax) document.getElementById('inwoners').innerText = cnt.toLocaleString('en');
  else done++
    let pMax = +document.getElementById('patienten').getAttribute("max");
  if (cnt < pMax) document.getElementById('patienten').innerText = cnt.toLocaleString('en');
  else done++
    let dMax = +document.getElementById('doden').getAttribute("max");
  if (cnt < dMax) document.getElementById('doden').innerText = cnt.toLocaleString('en');
  else done++



    document.getElementById('procent').innerHTML = ((Number(document.getElementById('doden').innerText.replace(/\D/g, "")) / Number(document.getElementById('patienten').innerText.replace(/\D/g, ""))) * 100).toLocaleString("en", {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2, // Minimum aantal getallen achter comma
      maximumFractionDigits: 2 // Maximum aantal getallen achter comma
    }) + "%"; // Zet een procent teken achter het getal
  if (done === 3) clearInterval(tId); 
}


function getCovidStats() {
  const cc = document.getElementById("countrySel").value; // Gekozen nummer van het land
  if (cc === "") return; // Als er een land gekozen is voer dan uit

  fetch('https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations/' + cc) // De database met gegevens van landen, CC is de country value die in de selector als waarde staat.
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json()
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      let population = data.location.country_population; // Inwoners van het land gekozen in de selector
      let update = data.location.last_updated; // Laatste update van de data
      let confirmedCases = data.location.latest.confirmed; // Aantal geregistreerde geinfecteerden in het gekozen land
      let deaths = data.location.latest.deaths; // Aantal doden in het gekozen land

      document.getElementById('inwoners').innerText = population.toLocaleString('en'); // Inwoneraantal van het land
      document.getElementById('update').innerText = update.substr(0, 10);
      document.getElementById('patienten').innerText = // Aantal geregistreerde geinfecteerden
      document.getElementById('patienten').setAttribute("max", confirmedCases) 
      document.getElementById('doden').innerText = 0; // Aantal doden
      document.getElementById('doden').setAttribute("max", deaths)  
      document.getElementById('procent').innerText = 0 + "%" // Percentage overleden mensen van het aantal besmette mensen
      cnt = 0;
      tId = setInterval(countUp, 0.0001); // Snelheid van de counter

      document.getElementById('preciezeAantal').innerText= confirmedCases;  // Dit laat het niet afgeronde aantal besmettingen voor het geselecteerde land zien
      tId = setInterval(countUp, 1500); 
    })
    .catch(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
  setInterval(getCovidStats, 43200000) // Zorgt ervoor dat de data om de 12 uur wordt geupdated
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
h1, h2 {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 font-size: 250%;
}

.subtitle, .over {
 padding: 20px;
 font-size: 150%;
}

body {
 background-color: #FFDC56;
 }

div {
 padding: 20px;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
 background-color: #005A9C;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 75%;
 }

 .logo {
  float: left;
 }

 /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
 .topnav a {
 float: right;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
 }
 
 /* Change the color of links on hover */
 .topnav a:hover {
 background-color: #FFDC56;
 color: black;
 }
 
 /* Add a color to the active/current link */
 .topnav a.active {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 color: white;
 }

.stats-container {
 text-align: center;
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
}
.location-container {
 display: inline-block;
}
.data-container {
 border: 2px solid #005A9C;
 margin-right: 30%;
 margin-left: 30%;
}

h4, {
 font-size: 85%;
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.over {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

.footer {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 bottom: 0;
 font-size: 75%;
 padding: 5px;
}


.maatregelen {
 width: 35%;
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;

}

.maatregelen-caption {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Coronavirus Statistieken</title>  
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="masker-emoji.png">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 <script src="chart.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="topnav">
  <h1 class= "logo">Coronavirus</h1> 
  <a href="over.html">Over</a>
  <a class="active" href="index.html">STATS</a>
   </div>

 <h2 class="subtitle">TITLE</h2>
 <div class="data-container">
  <div class="stats-container">
   <h4>TESTED POSITIVE</h4>
   <h1 id="patienten"></h1>
   <h4>DEATHS</h4>
   <h1 id="doden"></h1>
   <h4>Percentage deaths of patients</h4>
   <h1 id="procent"></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="location-container">
   <h4>Land</h4>
   <h1 id="country"><label for="countrySel">Country:</label>
    <select id="countrySel">
      <option value="169"> </option>
      <option value="120"> </option>
      <option value="116"> </option>
      <option value="201"> </option>
      <option value="137"> </option>
      <option value="187"> </option>
      <option value="143"> </option>
      <option value="225"> </option>
    </select>
     </h1>
   <h4>Population</h4>
   <h1 id="inwoners"></h1>
   <h4>Last update</h4>
   <h1 id="update"></h1>
  </div>  
 </div>
 <h1>test:</h1><h1 id="preciezeAantal"></h1>
 <canvas id="doughnut-chart"></canvas>
 <script>
  // Bar chart 
new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut-chart"), {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Deaths","Tested positive to Coronavirus"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: ".",
        backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850","#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f"],
        data: [100,200]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: { display: false },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Aantal besmettingen per land'
    }
  }
});
 </script>
 <h1 class="footer">Footer</a></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must get the "max" attribute by changing the selection see HTML script-tag:

```js
let tId;
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("countrySel").addEventListener("change", getCovidStats);
  document.getElementById("countrySel").value = "169";
  getCovidStats()
})

// Zorgt voor de optel annimatie
function countUp() {
  cnt += 100;
  let done = 0;
  let iMax = +document.getElementById('inwoners').getAttribute("max");
  if (cnt < iMax) document.getElementById('inwoners').innerText = cnt.toLocaleString('en');
  else done++
    let pMax = +document.getElementById('patienten').getAttribute("max");
  if (cnt < pMax) document.getElementById('patienten').innerText = cnt.toLocaleString('en');
  else done++
    let dMax = +document.getElementById('doden').getAttribute("max");
  if (cnt < dMax) document.getElementById('doden').innerText = cnt.toLocaleString('en');
  else done++



    document.getElementById('procent').innerHTML = ((Number(document.getElementById('doden').innerText.replace(/\D/g, "")) / Number(document.getElementById('patienten').innerText.replace(/\D/g, ""))) * 100).toLocaleString("en", {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2, // Minimum aantal getallen achter comma
      maximumFractionDigits: 2 // Maximum aantal getallen achter comma
    }) + "%"; // Zet een procent teken achter het getal
  if (done === 3) clearInterval(tId); 
}


function getCovidStats() {
  const cc = document.getElementById("countrySel").value; // Gekozen nummer van het land
  if (cc === "") return; // Als er een land gekozen is voer dan uit

  fetch('https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations/' + cc) // De database met gegevens van landen, CC is de country value die in de selector als waarde staat.
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json()
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      let population = data.location.country_population; // Inwoners van het land gekozen in de selector
      let update = data.location.last_updated; // Laatste update van de data
      let confirmedCases = data.location.latest.confirmed; // Aantal geregistreerde geinfecteerden in het gekozen land
      let deaths = data.location.latest.deaths; // Aantal doden in het gekozen land
        console.log(deaths)
      document.getElementById('inwoners').innerText = population.toLocaleString('en'); // Inwoneraantal van het land
      document.getElementById('update').innerText = update.substr(0, 10);
      document.getElementById('patienten').innerText = // Aantal geregistreerde geinfecteerden
      document.getElementById('patienten').setAttribute("max", confirmedCases) 
      document.getElementById('doden').innerText = 0; // Aantal doden
      document.getElementById('doden').setAttribute("max", deaths)  
      document.getElementById('procent').innerText = 0 + "%" // Percentage overleden mensen van het aantal besmette mensen
      cnt = 0;
      tId = setInterval(countUp, 0.0001); // Snelheid van de counter

      document.getElementById('preciezeAantal').innerText= confirmedCases;  // Dit laat het niet afgeronde aantal besmettingen voor het geselecteerde land zien
      tId = setInterval(countUp, 1500); 
    })
    .catch(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
  setInterval(getCovidStats, 43200000) // Zorgt ervoor dat de data om de 12 uur wordt geupdated
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
h1,
h2 {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 250%;
}

.subtitle,
.over {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 150%;
}

body {
    background-color: #ffdc56;
}

div {
    padding: 20px;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
    background-color: #005a9c;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 75%;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: right;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ffdc56;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4caf50;
    color: white;
}

.stats-container {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
.location-container {
    display: inline-block;
}
.data-container {
    border: 2px solid #005a9c;
    margin-right: 30%;
    margin-left: 30%;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 85%;
    color: gray;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.over {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 75%;
    padding: 5px;
}

.maatregelen {
    width: 35%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.maatregelen-caption {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Coronavirus Statistieken</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="masker-emoji.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="topnav">
        <h1 class="logo">Coronavirus</h1>
        <a href="over.html">Over</a>
        <a class="active" href="index.html">STATS</a>
    </div>

    <h2 class="subtitle">TITLE</h2>
    <div class="data-container">
        <div class="stats-container">
            <h4>TESTED POSITIVE</h4>
            <h1 id="patienten"></h1>
            <h4>DEATHS</h4>
            <h1 id="doden"></h1>
            <h4>Percentage deaths of patients</h4>
            <h1 id="procent"></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="location-container">
            <h4>Land</h4>
            <h1 id="country"><label for="countrySel">Country:</label>
                <select id="countrySel">
                    <option value="169"> </option>
                    <option value="120"> </option>
                    <option value="116"> </option>
                    <option value="201"> </option>
                    <option value="137"> </option>
                    <option value="187"> </option>
                    <option value="143"> </option>
                    <option value="225"> </option>
                </select>
            </h1>
            <h4>Population</h4>
            <h1 id="inwoners"></h1>
            <h4>Last update</h4>
            <h1 id="update"></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>test:</h1>
    <h1 id="preciezeAantal"></h1>
    <canvas id="doughnut-chart"></canvas>
    <script>
        let countrySel = document.getElementById('countrySel');
        countrySel.addEventListener("change", function () {
            deaths = document.getElementById("doden").getAttribute("max");
            positive_test = document.getElementById("patienten").getAttribute("max");

            new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut-chart"), {
                type: 'doughnut',
                data: {
                    labels: ["Deaths", "Tested positive to Coronavirus"],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: ".",
                            backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2", "#3cba9f", "#e8c3b9", "#c45850", "#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2", "#3cba9f"],
                            data: [deaths, positive_test]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    legend: { display: false },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Aantal besmettingen per land'
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <h1 class="footer">Footer</a></h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your chart logic in a function so you can pass `deaths` and `confirmedCases` as parameters to it. Then you call that function after `deaths` and `confirmedCases` have their values.

```js
let tId;
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("countrySel").addEventListener("change", getCovidStats);
  document.getElementById("countrySel").value = "169";
  getCovidStats()
})

// Zorgt voor de optel annimatie
function countUp() {
  cnt += 100;
  let done = 0;
  let iMax = +document.getElementById('inwoners').getAttribute("max");
  if (cnt < iMax) document.getElementById('inwoners').innerText = cnt.toLocaleString('en');
  else done++
    let pMax = +document.getElementById('patienten').getAttribute("max");
  if (cnt < pMax) document.getElementById('patienten').innerText = cnt.toLocaleString('en');
  else done++
    let dMax = +document.getElementById('doden').getAttribute("max");
  if (cnt < dMax) document.getElementById('doden').innerText = cnt.toLocaleString('en');
  else done++



    document.getElementById('procent').innerHTML = ((Number(document.getElementById('doden').innerText.replace(/\D/g, "")) / Number(document.getElementById('patienten').innerText.replace(/\D/g, ""))) * 100).toLocaleString("en", {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2, // Minimum aantal getallen achter comma
      maximumFractionDigits: 2 // Maximum aantal getallen achter comma
    }) + "%"; // Zet een procent teken achter het getal
  if (done === 3) clearInterval(tId); 
}

function getCovidStats() {
  const cc = document.getElementById("countrySel").value; // Gekozen nummer van het land
  if (cc === "") return; // Als er een land gekozen is voer dan uit

  fetch('https://coronavirus-tracker-api.herokuapp.com/v2/locations/' + cc) // De database met gegevens van landen, CC is de country value die in de selector als waarde staat.
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json()
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      let population = data.location.country_population; // Inwoners van het land gekozen in de selector
      let update = data.location.last_updated; // Laatste update van de data
      let confirmedCases = data.location.latest.confirmed; // Aantal geregistreerde geinfecteerden in het gekozen land
      let deaths = data.location.latest.deaths; // Aantal doden in het gekozen land
      showChart(deaths,confirmedCases);
      
      document.getElementById('inwoners').innerText = population.toLocaleString('en'); // Inwoneraantal van het land
      document.getElementById('update').innerText = update.substr(0, 10);
      document.getElementById('patienten').innerText = // Aantal geregistreerde geinfecteerden
      document.getElementById('patienten').setAttribute("max", confirmedCases) 
      document.getElementById('doden').innerText = 0; // Aantal doden
      document.getElementById('doden').setAttribute("max", deaths)  
      document.getElementById('procent').innerText = 0 + "%" // Percentage overleden mensen van het aantal besmette mensen
      cnt = 0;
      tId = setInterval(countUp, 0.0001); // Snelheid van de counter

      document.getElementById('preciezeAantal').innerText= confirmedCases;  // Dit laat het niet afgeronde aantal besmettingen voor het geselecteerde land zien
      tId = setInterval(countUp, 1500); 
    })
    .catch(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
  setInterval(getCovidStats, 43200000) // Zorgt ervoor dat de data om de 12 uur wordt geupdated
}

function showChart(deaths,confirmedCases){
  // Bar chart 
new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut-chart"), {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Deaths","Tested positive to Coronavirus"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: ".",
        backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f","#e8c3b9","#c45850","#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f"],
        data: [deaths,confirmedCases]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: { display: false },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Aantal besmettingen per land'
    }
  }
});
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
h1, h2 {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 font-size: 250%;
}

.subtitle, .over {
 padding: 20px;
 font-size: 150%;
}

body {
 background-color: #FFDC56;
 }

div {
 padding: 20px;
}

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
 background-color: #005A9C;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 75%;
 }

 .logo {
  float: left;
 }

 /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
 .topnav a {
 float: right;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
 }
 
 /* Change the color of links on hover */
 .topnav a:hover {
 background-color: #FFDC56;
 color: black;
 }
 
 /* Add a color to the active/current link */
 .topnav a.active {
 background-color: #4CAF50;
 color: white;
 }

.stats-container {
 text-align: center;
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
}
.location-container {
 display: inline-block;
}
.data-container {
 border: 2px solid #005A9C;
 margin-right: 30%;
 margin-left: 30%;
}

h4, {
 font-size: 85%;
  color: gray;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.over {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

.footer {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 bottom: 0;
 font-size: 75%;
 padding: 5px;
}


.maatregelen {
 width: 35%;
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;

}

.maatregelen-caption {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Coronavirus Statistieken</title>  
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="masker-emoji.png">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 <script src="chart.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="topnav">
  <h1 class= "logo">Coronavirus</h1> 
  <a href="over.html">Over</a>
  <a class="active" href="index.html">STATS</a>
   </div>

 <h2 class="subtitle">TITLE</h2>
 <div class="data-container">
  <div class="stats-container">
   <h4>TESTED POSITIVE</h4>
   <h1 id="patienten"></h1>
   <h4>DEATHS</h4>
   <h1 id="doden"></h1>
   <h4>Percentage deaths of patients</h4>
   <h1 id="procent"></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="location-container">
   <h4>Land</h4>
   <h1 id="country"><label for="countrySel">Country:</label>
    <select id="countrySel">
      <option value="169"> </option>
      <option value="120"> </option>
      <option value="116"> </option>
      <option value="201"> </option>
      <option value="137"> </option>
      <option value="187"> </option>
      <option value="143"> </option>
      <option value="225"> </option>
    </select>
     </h1>
   <h4>Population</h4>
   <h1 id="inwoners"></h1>
   <h4>Last update</h4>
   <h1 id="update"></h1>
  </div>  
 </div>
 <h1>test:</h1><h1 id="preciezeAantal"></h1>
 <canvas id="doughnut-chart"></canvas>
 <script>
 
 </script>
 <h1 class="footer">Footer</a></h1>
```